# how to parse json that has a child and child

Tags: android, json, android-studio

in this app i'm planned that the json is parse to fragments that when 'is_broken' is true it will only show on 1st fragment and 'is_repaired' is true it will only show on 2nd fragment and also 'is_ok' too. in this json has a data that has a child and it will be called in the same list but the key of json has the same key too which is 'name'

I'm trying to parse this json

```
     {
      "data": [
    {

            "name": "Table",
            "is_broken": false,
            "is_repaired": false,
            "is_ok": true,
           "asset_parent": {
             "name": "2nd Floor",
             "is_broken": false,
             "is_repaired": false,
             "is_ok": true,
             "asset_parent": {
               "name": "Grubi Building",
               "is_broken": false,
               "is_repaired": false,
               "is_ok": true
          }
          }
    },
{
          "name": "4th Floor",
          "is_broken": true,
          "is_repaired": false,
          "is_ok": false,
          "asset_parent": {
            "name": "Buni Building",
            "is_broken": true,
            "is_repaired": false,
            "is_ok": false
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

i'm trying to parse the data but just the name of the parent to put it into listview. this data has a child on it and i'm trying to call it just the parent of it on this fragment code

```
public static String in_aset = "aset";
    public static String in_gedung = "rektorat";
    public static String in_ruang = "000";
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    JSONArray str_json = null;
    ListView list, list2;
    AssetsAdapter adapter;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data_map = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_baik, container, false);

            new daftarAset().execute();

            return view;
        }

        class daftarAset extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String link_url = "https://example.com/api/assets";
                JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
                JSONObject json = jParser.AmbilJson(link_url);
                try {
                    str_json = json.getJSONArray("data");
                    for (int i = 0; i < str_json.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject ar = str_json.getJSONObject(i);
                        String aset = ar.getString("name").trim();
                        HashMap map = new HashMap();
                        map.put(in_aset, aset);
                        data_map.add(map);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        list = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.baik_list);
                        adapter = new AssetsAdapter(getActivity(), data_map);
                        list.setAdapter(adapter);
                        setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(list);
                    }
                });
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
            }

        }

        public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
            ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
            if (listAdapter == null) return;
            int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            int totalHeight = 0;
            View view = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                view = listAdapter.getView(i, view, listView);
                if (i == 0)
                    view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(desiredWidth, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                view.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                totalHeight += view.getMeasuredHeight();
            }
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
            listView.setLayoutParams(params);
            listView.requestLayout();
        }

and this is the adapter of code above

    public class AssetsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;

    public AssetsAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data =  d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        if (convertView == null) vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_chart, null);
        TextView textCucu = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.aset1);
        TextView textAnak = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.lokasi);
        TextView textBapak = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.waktu);
        HashMap<String, String> getdata = new HashMap<String, String>();
        getdata = data.get(position);
        textCucu.setText(getdata.get(BaikFragment.in_aset));
        textAnak.setText(getdata.get(BaikFragment.in_ruang));
        return vi;
    }
}
```

the TextView textCucu, textAnak, textBapak is reverse to listview that the json with key 'name' have to put in with the same listview from the json that has parent with children.
but when i trying code above i got this error messege

```
    E/JSON Parser: Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
                  Process: com.mqa.android.monas, PID: 30517
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.json.JSONArray org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                      at com.mqa.android.monas.Fragment.BaikFragment$daftarAset.doInBackground(BaikFragment.java:174)
                      at com.mqa.android.monas.Fragment.BaikFragment$daftarAset.doInBackground(BaikFragment.java:157)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                      at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb438b280: ver 2 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb438b280: ver 2 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb438b280: ver 2 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb438b280: ver 2 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb438b280: ver 2 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb438b280: ver 2 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb438b280: ver 2 0
E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.mqa.android.monas.Activity.AsetActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{dccaffa V.E..... R......D 0,0-1026,304} that was originally added here
                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:363)
                     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:271)
                     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
                     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
                     at com.mqa.android.monas.Fragment.BaikFragment$daftarAset.onPreExecute(BaikFragment.java:165)
                     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:591)
                     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:539)
                     at com.mqa.android.monas.Fragment.BaikFragment.onCreateView(BaikFragment.java:96)
                     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2354)
                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1419)
                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1740)
                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1809)
                     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:799)
                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2580)
                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2367)
                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2322)
                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2199)
                     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:651)
                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:145)
                     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1236)
                     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1084)
                     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1614)
                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:714)
                     at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:91)
                     at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1361)
                     at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:784)
                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                     at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
                     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2015)


at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(View
```

please help. how can i parse the json data that has a child in the same list view with the same key of json. or what code should i write to parse that json into the list

Comment: Your json is invalid 2nd node of array is closing without  `}` jsonobject closing braces.

Comment: i'm sorry, it good now @SohailZahid

Comment: you missed the `,` at line 8 at after  `"is_ok": true`  it should be like  `"is_ok": true,`

Comment: done :), im just a little bit evolve it hehe

Comment: now it will work give it a try

Comment: no it don't. my code was wrong. i'm a little confused how to parse it from a code

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `NullPointerException` at line

```
str_json = json.getJSONArray("data");
```

debug and check why you are getting json as null , keep a null check before parsing

```
 try {
          if(json!=null){
                str_json = json.getJSONArray("data");
                for (int i = 0; i < str_json.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject ar = str_json.getJSONObject(i);
                    String aset = ar.getString("name").trim();
                    HashMap map = new HashMap();
                    map.put(in_aset, aset);
                    data_map.add(map);
                }
             }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

or catch for `Exception` instead of `JSONException` (Not Recommended)

Comment: why String cannot be converted to jsonObject?

Comment: It can be converted

Answer (score -1):

Please never parse json this way again.

Google has deploy an incredible library to parse json in a robust and easy way.
Just :

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
gson.fromJson(jsonString)
```

For more information on how to setup this library here is the link to a tutorial : http://borntocode.fr/android-mettre-en-place-et-utiliser-gson-pour-faciliter-lutilisation-du-json/

Comment: it depends very much on the use case and the source of the JSON what is the best way to parse JSON. Gson is one possibility but often not necessary and even not the best choice.